# Tidy up and combine document.ready and eventlistener

Tags: javascript, function

I have this code and it works great:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

        if (window.location.href.indexOf("emotion--1") > -1) {
            $('#scroll-down').addClass('scroll-down');       
            $('#scroll-down').deleteClass('invisible');
        }  

        if (window.location.href.indexOf("emotion--2") > -1) {
            $('#shirt').addClass('draw-shirt');       
            $('#scroll-down-2').addClass('scroll-down');   
            $('#shirt, #scroll-down-2').deleteClass('invisible');
        }  
        
        if (window.location.href.indexOf("emotion--3") > -1) {
            $('#dress').addClass('draw-dress');       
            $('#scroll-down-3').addClass('scroll-down');               
            $('#garbage, #scroll-down-3').deleteClass('invisible');
        } 
        });
        
  
    window.addEventListener('hashchange', function() {
   
        if (location.hash === '#emotion--1') {
            $('#scroll-down').addClass('scroll-down');       
            $('#scroll-down').deleteClass('invisible');
        }       

        if (location.hash === '#emotion--2') {
            $('#shirt').addClass('draw-shirt');       
            $('#scroll-down-2').addClass('scroll-down');   
            $('#shirt, #scroll-down-2').deleteClass('invisible');
        }  
        
        if (location.hash === '#emotion--3') {
            $('#dress').addClass('draw-dress');       
            $('#scroll-down-3').addClass('scroll-down');               
            $('#dress, #scroll-down-3').deleteClass('invisible');
        }         
        });
```

As you can see, both functions are almost similar. What can I do to tidy it up and to shorten it? I already have this:

```
    if ( (window.location.href.indexOf("emotion--1") > -1) || (location.hash === '#emotion--1') ) {
            $('#scroll-down').addClass('scroll-down');       
            $('#scroll-down').deleteClass('invisible');
    }  

    if ( (window.location.href.indexOf("emotion--2") > -1) || (location.hash === '#emotion--2') ) {
        $('#shirt').addClass('draw-shirt');       
        $('#scroll-down-2').addClass('scroll-down');   
        $('#shirt, #scroll-down-2').deleteClass('invisible');
    }  
    
    if ( (window.location.href.indexOf("emotion--3") > -1) || (location.hash === '#emotion--3') ) {
        $('#dress').addClass('draw-dress');       
        $('#scroll-down-3').addClass('scroll-down');               
        $('#garbage, #scroll-down-3').deleteClass('invisible');
    }
```

But where do I have to put the Eventlistener and the document.ready code? I'm still new to JavaScript.

Comment: Define a named function, and call it from both `hashchange` and `ready`.

Comment: BTW, `string1.indexOf(string2) > -1` can be simplified to `string1.includes(string2)`

Comment: You don't need to check both `location.href` and `location.hash`, since the hash is included in href.

Comment: In general it works like this: https://pastebin.com/Aj6npKJZ

Comment: Why do you write `window.location` in one case, but just `location` in the other? You should be consistent in your coding.